# Is accessing a member of a struct in its own initializer undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, initialization

Consider:

```
struct A { void do_something() {} };

struct B {
  A& a;
  B(A& a) : a{a} { a.do_something(); }
};

struct C {
  A a; B b;
  C(A& a) : b{a} {}
};

int main() {
  C c{ c.a };
}
```

It seems possible that this *could* be made to work, because:

- even before `c` is initialized, we know its memory layout and the address of `c.a`
- we don't actually *use* `c.a` until it is initialized.

Additionally, I didn't get a warning under a few different compilers.

However, I experienced some extremely odd behaviour (a bit later on) that could only be down to doing something undefined, and which only went away when I reorganised my program to avoid this pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Accessing `c.a` *outside `C`'s constructor* and before `c`'s lifetime has begun is a problem. It's a bit like `int x = x;`.

Comment: But my program works perfectly!

Comment: @STU, undefined behavior doesn't mean that the code wouldn't work, (and your current snippet works well, and should work well for every sane compiler).. But UB also means the compiler is permitted to generate code that will reformat your PC; ;-)

Comment: [CWG1530](http://wg21.link/cwg1530) is relevant in this case, I think.

Comment: @bogdan thanks, this is the answer as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @STU: I find that assertion highly improbable!

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you are accessing an object's member outside the object and before the lifetime of the object commences.

> [**$12.7: 1:**](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#class.cdtor-1) For an object with a non-trivial constructor,
>   referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before
>   the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior...

As to why it compiles fine: A name can be used after its point of declaration ... And Quoting the C++ Standard draft... (emphasis mine):

> [**$3.3.2 : 1:**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#1) The point of declaration for a name is immediately
>   after its complete declarator (Clause [[dcl.decl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl)) and **before** its
>   [*initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#initializer) (if any)...

And [*initalizer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#initializer) is defined to have the syntax (reproduced here partially):

> *initializer*...
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     brace-or-equal-initializer
>     ( expression-list )
>
> brace-or-equal-initializer:
>     = initializer-clause
>     braced-init-list
>
> initializer-clause:
>     assignment-expression
>     braced-init-list
> . . .
> ```

The above is the same reason why this will compile:

```
int k(k);
int m{m};
int b = b;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the grammar (which just describes how C++ source is parsed) is at all relevant to the runtime.  This section just tells us at which point in the source text a particular token starts having a specific meaning, but that is a point in text not a point in time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my previous answer,

---

Your code is a crafty one... Because, despite the *supposed* UB with using an object before its initialized, the behaviour of your code is *apparently* well defined..

How?
In the construction of `c`, the following sequence of events will happen:

1. You call `C`'s constructor, `C(A& a) : b{a} {}` which takes a reference to an object of type `A`. (A reference is just like an address, and as you rightly mentioned, the address of `c.a` is known at compile time). Your call is: `C c{ c.a };` and the compiler is fine with that since `c.a` is an accessible name
2. Due to the order of declaration of `C`'s members...

   ```
   struct C {
     A a; B b;
     C(A& a) : b{a} {}
   };
   ```

   the object `a` is initialized before `b`.
3. Thus, `a` becomes alive before its use in the member initializer... `b{a}`

---

But again, you can be smoked by [optimizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)...

Comment: This was my reasoning, but like I said it ended up giving me weird bugs 20 lines later until I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a pretty well-defined order of construction. First (non-virtual) base classes are initialized. Members are initialized next, in order of their declaration in the class (and **ignoring** the order of the initializer list), and only after the last member has been initialized will the body of the constructor be entered.

In this case, it means that the ctors are called in the order `A::A, B::B, C::C`.

You **would** have an issue if C was declared as

```
struct C {
  B b; A a; 
  C(A& a) : b{a} {}
};
```

Comment: Well, there's still the issue of [12.7p1], which says *For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. [...]*. However, this may be adjusted in the future (see my comment on the question).

Comment: @bogdan: I noticed it, read the CWG issue, upvoted you and then wrote the answer. As you can infer from the CWG issue, all "reasonable interpretations" allow the formation of a reference.

Comment: The "reasonable interpretation" in the CWG issue refers to the interpretation of the word *access* in [3.8], and that was clarified in the meantime in the Standard wording, so we agree on that part. I commented because I read your answer to mean "You're fine", and I don't think that's a safe assumption to make as long as [12.7p1] unambiguously makes the code result in UB (in `C c{c.a};`, the expression `c.a` is evaluated before `c`'s constructor starts executing).